# Blender how to create 2D shape with smooth and sharp edges

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

Dears, I am new to Blender 3D and I am struggling at creating 2D flat objects that have sharp vertices/edges and smooth vertices/edges I create my object, I select some vertices as "sharp" or "crease" but after applying the subdivision surface modifier the entire object is smoothed out, including the vertices marked as sharp. I was not able to find a tutorial.. Thank you for your help.

Comment: to sharpen you need to create some additional edges close to the existing one you want to sharp,  I don't think Crease could help with 2D shapes.

Comment: I think you need to post some images. Also have a look at Autosmooth in the object properties and changing the angle. This works when and object is marked Smooth shading.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using Bezier Curves instead, if you don't need clean topology. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58626/is-it-possible-to-import-the-outline-or-profile-of-something-from-a-picture-to-u or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55205/how-can-i-make-a-planes-edges-taper-inwards

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos  just beat me to it: you want to have a look at 2D Bezier Curves. Although the editing interface is not quite as intuitive or flexible as some other apps, you can soon get used to it ..  there's a good little intro video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTzl64dshpA)

Answer (score 1):

To sharpen you need to create some additional edges close to the existing one you want to sharp, I don't think *Crease* could help with 2D shapes.

[image]